# Emulador do android studio fechando sozinho

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, emulador

beleza?
Recentemente, migrei para o Kubuntu e nele tentei instalar o Android Studio para que eu pudesse emular os meus aplicativos. Segui [esse tutorial](https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/linux) e consegui instalar o AS com sucesso. Porém, quando tento inciar o emulador, ele da aquela tela de loading do google e depois simplesmente fecha, apresentando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já até tentei algumas soluções da internet e até mesmo de uma comunidade no discord, mas nada resolveu.
Ps: Sou iniciante nos sistemas operacionais Linux.

"A virtualização está ativada na Bios?"
Sim, verifiquei diversas vezes

Answer (score 0):

Depois de dias procurando, encontrei uma solução para o meu problema. O post original pode ser encontrado [Aqui](https://www.programmersought.com/article/62676436011/).

Os passos para resolver esse problema foram:

1. Vá até a pasta `.android` localizada na pasta do seu usuário (Ela fica oculta por padrão). Dentro dessa pasta você encontrará outra pasta com o nome de `avd`, onde estão as pastas dos emuladores criados.
2. Dentro da pasta `avd`, localize a pasta do seu emulador e dentro dela você encontrará um arquivo nomeado de `config.ini`. Nesse arquivo você encontrará diversas configurações, dentro delas a `hw.gpu.enabled=yes` e a `hw.gpu.mode=auto`.

3.Troque os valores dessas configurações para: `hw.gpu.enabled = no` `hw.gpu.mode = off` e salve o arquivo.

Apos seguir esses passos, o emulador abriu normalmente para mim, mas caso continue o erro reinicie o sistema.